# How to detect node uses which ports to communicate with other nodes

Tags: networking, ps, tcpdump

In linux, I could like to know the node uses which ports to communicate with other nodes automatically. Some methods in my mind:

1) tcpdump, then figure out which port to talk with other node, by which protocol.
2) ps to list all processes, then use process to see which port it is using.

Could expert give some advice/suggestions/hints?

Comment: Read `man lsof`. `sudo lsof -i` will show all open internet connections.